# Output of tries traversal seems to be incorrect in c

Tags: c, data-structures, recursion, struct, recursive-datastructures

this is the function witch is used to print all words in the tries .But some time  I    am getting error .Can't understand where went wrong ???please help me..thanks a lots.

```
typedef int boolean;
typedef struct test_struct test_struct_t;
struct test_struct {
    boolean end;
    int freq;
    char* word;
    test_struct_t *next;
    test_struct_t *child[26];
};
typedef struct trie trie_t;
struct trie {
    struct test_struct *root;
    int count;
};
void printContent(test_struct_t *head) {
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++) {
        if(head->child[i]->w!='1') {
            if(head->child[i]->end==TRUE) {
                printf("%s (%d)\n",head->child[i]->word,head->child[i]->freq);
            }
            printContent(head->child[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting? Also, can you please format your code properly (add indentation, comments, whitespace, etc.)?

Comment: `typedef int boolean;`! Why would you do that?

Comment: Which error can you specify it?

Comment: it seems to be logical error I mean sometime all words which have been entered are shown by calling this function sometime not

Comment: Actually I want to know how to travels in recursive way to print all words in it.

Answer (score 0):

in this line `if(head->child[i]->w!='1'){`, why there is a `w`?

maybe you can try this:
`if( (head->child[i] != null) && head->child[i]->word!='1'){`

Comment: struct test_struct
   { boolean end;
 int freq;
 char* word;
 char w;
 test_struct_t *next;
 test_struct_t *child[26]; 
    }; here w is the place where character is stored.